# Possibility of praying in Masjid Al-Aqsa (Jerusalem)

Tags: israel, jerusalem

I will be visiting Jerusalem in a week. Is Israeli government allow to pray in Masjid Al-Aksa? Can I go there freely? Is there anything I should know before I go there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are able to enter the country, i.e. if they let you in, then you will be able to enter the Al-Aqsa Mosque. In principle, as a Muslim it is much easier to access the Temple Mount that as a non Muslim. You have more entry points at your disposal, and you can avoid the queues at the al-Magrhib bridge. Once you are inside you can of course pray. The contrary would be strange in a place like this. Allahu Akbar.

Comment: Thnx for the answer. Anything I have to be careful about entering Israel? At what hours are we allowed to enter the Temple Mount?

Comment: Entering Israel is quite straightforward: http://www.fco.gov.uk/en/travel-and-living-abroad/travel-advice-by-country/middle-east-north-africa/israel-occupied#entryRequirements However, havng palestinian ancestors or being a German born before 1928 will complicate things. Moreover, if you have stamps from certain arabic countries or from Iran in your passport, you might get some special treatment at the border.

Comment: Regaridng the opening hours I don't know. For tourists it is fairly restrictive, but for prayers they are more generous.

Comment: Entering Israel is exactly like entering the United States or Britain. They are very straightforward and courteous. I was surprised when I first went because of all the things you hear about Israel, but most of it is BS. You never feel unsafe or threatened.

Comment: Entering the US is not what I would call straightforwrad. It's hassle and can be humiliating.